# gulp --production laravel elixir fails on webfonts

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webfonts, laravel-elixir

I'm using Laravel 5.3 elixir to mix the assets, my js app in angular generally. Webpack is behind it. Everything runs, files compile to single app.js , even my css is there. I use bootstrap to skin the app. But when I run `gulp --production` it fails because of parsing/uglyfing webfont.

```
Error: Unexpected token: operator (<)',
  fileName: '/home/user/www/laravel/89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg',
  lineNumber: 1,
  stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/arek/www/laravel/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)\n
```

My gulpfile is easy:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(mix => {
    mix.webpack('app.js')
    .browserSync({
        'proxy': 'http://localhost:8000'
    })
    ;
});
```

And inside my app.js I just import css of bootstrap (of course I use css loader for webpack).

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import routing from './app.config';
import login from './features/login';

angular.module('app', [uirouter, login]).
config(routing);
```

Have you had simillar issue with new elixir, or with webpack? Maybe I'm missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that using paths inside css were the issue. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/597 explained a lot. Now my asset loader(test var) looks like

`test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,`

instead of

`test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,`